# Is there a way to install MySQL via Dockerfile in an Ubuntu docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to install MySQL in an Ubuntu docker container but I cant find clear instructions in the internet on how to do that...

Comment: You want mysql docker container on ubuntu os, or mysql in your ubuntu container?

Answer (score 2):

just to clarify,
install via Docker file means build and image based on ubuntu plus packages you need in it. Like myssql.

meanwhile container is a running instance of any docker image (which can be started and stopped like any pc).

so in you case it looks like you want to build an image with mysql in it.

1. since you want ubuntu:

`FROM ubuntu:18.04`

2. since you want mysql in you need one more line in Dockerfile:

`RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y mysql-server`

you can also install what every else you need in your docker image, like cron, or python.

just add new lines with `RUN apt-get install -y ....`

3. then `docker build -t "desired-imag-name"` to build an image in folder where Dockerfiel is.

to run it you need some blocker process to keep you container running:

4. `docker run -d desired-imag-name bash -c "sleep infinity"`

that would work for testing purposes, but you need something more complicated for production - instead of `bash -c "sleep infinity"` some sh script which would stop mysql properly before terminating container.

Comment: I would recommend using the [official `mysql` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) instead. You don't even need to write a Dockerfile to use it... just `docker run mysql:8.0.21`

Comment: agree, but the question was on how to install on ubuntu. Sometimes it make sense because official image may use something like `FROM alpine` which is pretty annoying.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The official mysql Docker image is based on `debian:buster-slim`. Compatible with ubuntu, but of course not ubuntu.